# 5 Iyar vs. 10 Adar

Tags: minhag, calendar, chagim-holidays, adar, yom-haatzmaut

In Jewish tradition, we generally commemorate the ends of wars rather than their beginnings (e.g./i.e. Chanuka, Purim). The commemoration of the rebirth of Israel as the Jewish homeland in the past century is popularly (in non-Haredi circles) celebrated on 5 Iyar, the day when the declaration of independence from British rule was made, which triggered a war with the Arab world. Is there any rabbinic authority who proposes that the actual commemoration should occur on 10 Adar, [Ink Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ink_Flag) Day, when the war ostensibly ended (and without bloodshed) or, at least, addresses the issue?

[image: B&W image of soldiers raising an Israeli flag[2]]

"The Ink-Drawn National Flag" by Micha Perry, licensed CC BY-NC-SA 2.0 by Government Press Office

Comment: 5 Iyar doesn't commemorate the beginning of the war. It's completely unrelated.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's one answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA (I guess I was arguing that the Jewish people had not really been saved in the traditional Jewish sense till they defeated the Arabs [frying pan to fire is nisht keyn geulah]. But I suppose you could argue that 10 Adar was a giluy milsa lmafreya on 5 Iyar.)

Comment: @DoubleAA For secular Zionists, on the other hand, for whom humanist self-determination is the utmost value (and for whom commemoration of the Holocaust occurs specifically  on the anniversary of the doomed Warsaw uprising) the declaration of independence is the concept to celebrate (regardless of how the war would have turned out) in sharp contradistinction to the concept of divine salvation celebrated traditionally.

Comment: [Chanuka doesn't celebrate the end of the war.](http://www.jewishhistory.org/the-war-after-chanukah/) It celebrates the rededication of the Beit Hamikdash. Similarly, if asked, most zionists would claim to be celebrating the day Hashem gave us the gift of the State of Israel. Not a Geulah from some threat of destruction or the War of Independence. I've never heard of any rabbinic authority which suggests celebrating a different day, though a common objection to celebrating 5th Iyar is that the war began on that day.

Comment: @Meh Fair enough. However, the interpretation of the Tur that the very name of the holiday commemorates the fact that they rested on the 25th, as well as the fact that that was also the basis used to set the dates on which we set Purim (as recorded in the Megilla), indicates that that it is the cessation of hostilities upon which we traditionally commemorate salvations. Is there a basis to instead follow guidelines set by secular/antireligious institutions?

Comment: @loewian [Yom Ha'atzma'ut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Ha%27atzmaut#Religious_customs) was established as a Jewish holiday by the Chief Rabbinate of Israel in 1950-51. The Chief Rabbis at the time were [R' Yitzchak HaLevi Herzog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_HaLevi_Herzog) and [R' Ben-Zion Meir Hai Uziel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben-Zion_Meir_Hai_Uziel).

Comment: @IsaacMoses That may be, but it's doubtful that their sole consideration was tradition in choosing the day e.g. the authoritative site you link uses this language: "In response to widespread public feeling..." My question is whether any other religious authority disagreed about the choice of day based on Jewish historical precedent. (Separately, but relatedly, I asked about the choice of name for the holiday:http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57483/celebrate-5-iyar-not-yom-haatzmaut)

Comment: @loewian Your question is a valid one. It is invalid, however, to assume or assert that these *gedolim* rejected tradition and "instead follow[ed] guidelines set by secular/antireligious institutions." Incidentally, besides Chanuka, Chag HaPesach also doesn't fall on the "date of cessation of hostilities." I'm not sure what other traditional precedents you'd consider, but the case for the rule that you assert is far from ironclad based on the small set of salvation-based holidays that we currently celebrate.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Fair enough. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23063/discussion-between-loewian-and-isaac-moses).

Comment: "Widespread public feeling" was also a factor in the establishment of Purim.  See the Malbim on משלוח מנות איש לרעהו.

Comment: Does the large picture at the bottom of the post add or distract?