# Celebrate 5 Iyar; not "Yom HaAtzmaut"?

Tags: names, heresy, yom-haatzmaut, zionism

Do any religious-zionist figures (or anyone else for that matter) advocate the commemoration of 5 Iyar but reject the adoption by the religious community of the name "Yom HaAtzma'ut" - "Independence Day" as a secular concept foreign to Judaism and based on the atheist and humanist values of self-determination on the part of the secular Zionists?

Comment: To clarify - you're looking for someone who supports the holiday itself but not the NAME of the holiday?

Comment: @Bachrach44 Yes.

Comment: FWIW, I have kind of the reverse, I acknowledge the day itself, as Yom haAtzmaut, as an important day in modern Jewish history, however I don't modify my tefillot in any way (in fact, I have a note in my calendar to remember tachanun, because it's so close to Nissan).